# Japanese / South Korean resident cheating in video games in or from another country

Tags: internet, japan

In Japan and South Korea, broadly speaking, cheating in video games is illegal and it's possible to see jail time or fines for something even like modifying Wii local save files. ("Video games" may not be important, but it has been the motivation behind some legislature, so I may be being overly specific)

I'm curious about some edge cases. Are the following likely to be punishable?

1. A Japanese/South Korean citizen/PR visits the United States, and while there, cheats in online games (possibly for profit)
2. If that's okay, what if the account cheated on is then used afterwards upon return to the home country?
3. Whether or not the cheating occurred while in Japan or South Korea, does it matter if the company has a legal entity established in the country?
4. What about paying a foreign citizen (who never goes to Japan or South Korea) to cheat on your account?